# How to make hosts files updated automaticly?

Tags: java, networking, lan, hostname, hosts

Trying to to get the hostname of a given ip address in a LAN using java.

The remote machine is pinged as well, but the returned hostname is the ip address itself.

Read somewhere else, that this problem is because the " hosts file " under system32/drivers/etc/hosts doesn't contain the needed information, so i added it manually, and there i was able to get it from the java program.

What's strange is that,sometime before that, I connected my computer to another LAN (using my phone) and didn't have to do the file's editing to get the hostname of a remote machine, i guess that it was already available in the file.

My question is, is there any way to configure the router so that it adds the hostnames by itself in the right file ? because actually when i check the main page of the router, (which can be obtained by typing 192.168.1.1 in a navigator) the hostnames of the connected machines to the router are displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A lookup of a Hostname by IP can be realized like this: `java.net.InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1").getHostName()`, alternatively you could use `InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {(byte) 192, (byte) 168, (byte) 1, (byte) 1)});`

The lookup will involve both /etc/hosts and configured DNS servers.

In case you need more basic DNS information, one can use DNS lookups via JNDI (see `com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory` and [JNDI/DNS Service Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-dns.html)).

In this case a real DNS server is required.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I know it's done by calling, java.net.InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1").getHostName(). But it doesn't return the hostname, it does return the adress, except when i add manually the host name in the /etc/hosts file.